# Create App Package for WinUI3 using Azure Devops CI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, uwp, winui-3, winui

I am trying to create the app package using Azure CI for WinUI3 project. I tried referencing this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps) and used the same yaml(yaml for UWP) but no artifacts are generated, the same yaml works for UWP project.